# test android app on lg p-690

Tags: android

can I test the app on this device if I don't have a data cable? I don't know how to do it or even if it is possible.

Do you need some specific phones in order to test the application?

Thank you,
Ryan

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2604727/1319061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just email yourself the apk file if you have no way of transferring the file across, when you goto look at the attachement it will give you the option to install.  You must make sure that in your application settings menu on the phone you turn on the option that allows you to install apps from untrusted sources though.